# How to add more rows in pyspark df by column value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, flatmap

I'm stuck with this problem quite a while and probably making it bigger than really it is. I will try to simplify it.

I'm using pyspark and data frame functions along my code.

I already have a df as:

```
+--+-----+---------+
|id|col1 |col2     |
+--+-----+---------+
|1 |Hello|Repeat   |
|2 |Word |Repeat   |
|3 |Aux  |No repeat|
|4 |Test |Repeat   |
+--+-----+---------+
```

What I want to achieve is to repeat the df's rows when col2 is 'Repeat' increasing col1's values in value+1.

```
+--+-----+---------+------+
|id|col1 |col2     |col3  |
+--+-----+---------+------+
|1 |Hello|Repeat   |Hello1|
|1 |Hello|Repeat   |Hello2|
|1 |Hello|Repeat   |Hello3|
|2 |Word |Repeat   |Word1 |
|2 |Word |Repeat   |Word2 |
|2 |Word |Repeat   |Word3 |
|3 |Aux  |No repeat|Aux   |
|4 |Test |Repeat   |Test1 |
|4 |Test |Repeat   |Test2 |
|4 |Test |Repeat   |Test3 |
+--+-----+---------+------+
```

My first approach was to use **withColumn** operator to create a new column with udf's help:

```
my_func = udf(lambda words: (words + str(i + 1 for i in range(3))), StringType())
df = df\
    .withColumn('col3', when(col('col2') == 'No Repeat', col('col1'))
                            .otherwise(my_func(col('col1'))))
```

But when I evaluate this in a **df.show(10,False)** it's throw me an error. My guessing is because I just can't create more rows with **withColumn** function in that way.

So I decide to go for another approach with no success also. Using a **rdd.flatMap**:

```
test = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: (row if (row.col2== 'No Repeat') else (row.col1 + str(i+1) for i in range(3))))
print(test.collect())
```

But here I'm losing the **df schema** and I can not throw out the full row on the else condition, it **only throw me the col1 words plus it's iterator**.

Do you know any proper way to solve this?

At the end my problem is that I do not get a properly way to create more rows based on column values because I'm quite new in this world. Also answers that I found seems not to fit this problem.

All help will be appreciate.

Comment: maybe have a look at `DataFrame.explode` method?

Comment: I was fighting with rdd.flatmap due performance but yes explode method is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is use a condition and assign an array , then explode,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df.withColumn("test",F.when(df['col2']=='Repeat',
       F.array([F.lit(str(i)) for i in range(1,4)])).otherwise(F.array(F.lit(''))))
  .withColumn("col3",F.explode(F.col("test"))).drop("test")
  .withColumn("col3",F.concat(F.col("col1"),F.col("col3")))).show()
```

A neater version of the same as suggested by @MohammadMurtazaHashmi would look like:

```
(df.withColumn("test",F.when(df['col2']=='Repeat',
     F.array([F.concat(F.col("col1"),F.lit(str(i))) for i in range(1,4)]))
    .otherwise(F.array(F.col("col1"))))
    .select("id","col1","col2", F.explode("test"))).show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+---------+------+
| id| col1|     col2|  col3|
+---+-----+---------+------+
|  1|Hello|   Repeat|Hello1|
|  1|Hello|   Repeat|Hello2|
|  1|Hello|   Repeat|Hello3|
|  2| Word|   Repeat| Word1|
|  2| Word|   Repeat| Word2|
|  2| Word|   Repeat| Word3|
|  3|  Aux|No repeat|   Aux|
|  4| Test|   Repeat| Test1|
|  4| Test|   Repeat| Test2|
|  4| Test|   Repeat| Test3|
+---+-----+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @anky. At the end I'm following a very similar approach like yours. I was avoiding to use explode function due performance, but just now explode should be fine.

Comment: @anky you could also concat like this `F.array([F.concat(F.col("col1"),F.lit(str(i))) for i in range(1,4)]))`

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi that is indeed neater . I was wondering such methods should exist as I am familiar to such operations using pandas but didnt know to do that in pyspark. Thanks for enlightening me :)